# returning incorrect floating point value

Tags: java, android

I have a method getFar() which should return 5.1f:

```
 float far = 5.1f;

 public float getFar()
 {return far;}
```

But when I call it from another class

```
  System.out.println("Far: "+ mRenderer.getFar());
```

it returns different values every time. In one run it can be 5.25..., in another 5.78..., etc

How can I return 5.1f?

Comment: The code you provided is correct (except for a missing `;`). Are you sure you are not updating the variable elsewhere, resulting in the different values?

Comment: as Veger said, are you sure the variable is not being reassigned somewhere else?
You could try adding a final to its declaration and see if the compiler complains somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that mRenderer.getFar() is calling your getFar()? Is it an overload or override of a method from a parent class?  Is mRenderer being reassigned to a different instance with a different value for far?

Comment: figured. yes,it was being incremented.